# Как указать символ с которого должен начинатся выбор слов, но не включая его?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

```
var str = '"Hello"';
```

Помогите составить регулярное выражение, чтобы выбрать только слово **Hello** .
То есть выражение должно быть составленно так, чтобы выбрать все между кавычек, но их в конечный результат не включать.
В доках написанно, что запись **(?:x)** говорит начать с х но не включать его в массив строки. И вот толи я не правильно понял, то ли... Не получается у меня.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это называется [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=x)(.*)
```

Правило типа `(?:...)` просто осуществляет группировку без выделения в подмаску.

Конкретно с `"hello"`:

```
(?<=")([^"]*)(?=")
```

Comment: Такое ощущение, что это "вперед и назад смотрящие", но их в js нет вродебы и ваш пример у меня ошибку выдает. Почему?

Comment: @vas, да, на теги не посмотрел. Там проще выдирать с кавычками и обрезать.

Comment: А может по-простому: <http://jsfiddle.net/s87W5/>? Ну то есть <http://jsfiddle.net/DQ23q/>, конечно.

Comment: @vas: Хм. А откуда регулярное выражение будет знать, что `"Hel"l"""o"worl"d"` надо разбить как `Hel"l"""o` + `d`, а не как-то по-другому? Если кавычка может быть внутри, откуда код узнает, это завершающая кавычка или нет?

Comment: @vas: А вы видели второй пример? (<http://jsfiddle.net/DQ23q/>) Он именно это и выводит.

Comment: @Etki, не видел, но увидел. У меня ещё вопрос - зачем Вы кавычки экранируете? И [^"] означает не включая кавычки?

Comment: @vas: По привычке из C#. И правда, бэкслеш не нужен: http://jsfiddle.net/DQ23q/3/